# save "Use Default Value" for these magento attributes

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

I duplicated the product from the client side and updated the new product. The site have different store views.

I want to make sure that when saving/updating "Use Default Value" checkbox should be checked for Visibility, price, special price etc.

But when using save() function it is always getting unchecked.. How to save "Use Default Value" for these magento attributes.

Comment: you can do by hard coded, therefore, isn't good idea.

Comment: If you want to make sure that visibility, price and so on have the same value you can change the Scope of the attribute (from Manage Attributes) from Store View to Global.

Answer (score 0):

Best deal would be backup your data first.
Then create a script for which product you want to set the default value in such a way that it deletes the related row from that entity attribute table.

Thanks